# getting error while deploying laravel 5.5 project

Tags: laravel-5, project-hosting

Deploying my laravel project on Linux hosting using cpanel. Project running on localhost very well but once i put on hosting, it is giving me following error.

> Warning: require_once(): It is not safe to rely on the system's
>   timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting
>   or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of
>   those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in
>   /home/sachinpa/public_html/public/index.php on line 52
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in
>   /home/sachinpa/public_html/public/index.php on line 52.

Comment: The solution is simple here. Read the error message. It says `You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function`

Comment: not getting exactly what to do or how to implement this. please guide